# How to solve this conditional probability problem which includes addition?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There is this homework question from a yr 11 Cambridge textbook, which is:

[image]

In the textbook, the conditional probability formula for dependent events is:
$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}$,
where $P(A|B)$ means the probability of $A$, given that $B$ has occurred, and $P(A∩B)$ means $P(A\ and\ B)$.

For the question above, I have tried using listing the possible sums, e.g $(10+5)$, $(10+10)$ and $(10+20)$ and then finding the probabilities of each without replacement, for example, to find the probability of the sum being $(10+10)$, I did $(\frac{3}{9} * \frac{2}{8})$ but I struggled to plug this into the formula.

How can I use the equation to solve the question when it is asking for the *sums* of the outcomes?

Comment: How are the events A and B defined in the book?

Comment: It seems you are thinking of this as sampling without replacement and with ordering.  So $10+5$ is really "first pick a 10, then pick a 5" and could be written $(10,5)$, and is different from $(5,10)$. Now in the $(i,j)$ notation, which ones correspond to $A\cap B$? Which ones correspond to $B=\{\mbox{at least one 10}\}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you tried but it sounds as if you are overcomplicating things.  Sums have very little to do with it.

Let $A$ be the event that the total was \$20 or more, let $B$ be the event that at least one \$10 was picked.  You want
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\ .$$
Now $P(B)$ should be easy enough to calculate (hint: $P(B^c)$ is probably easier), and $A\cap B$ is the event that either two \$10 or a \$10 and a \$20 are chosen.